# Linear Equation unknown variables and number of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Q. True of False
The four linear equations with Three unknown variables is always inconsistent?

Is it true or false?

I thought of this example

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0
\end{array}\;\middle\vert\;\begin{array}{c}2\\3\\4\\0\end{array}\right)$$

This is consistent right?
SO it should be false?

Comment: Yes, the answer is "False," as your example shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your example provides represents a system of four equations in three unknown variables, yet ***is*** consistent, and so you've provided a "counterexample" to the claim. Hence the claim is false.

That's precisely how one can disprove a proposition about *all* "such-and-such" being "this-or-that": find *just one* counterexample that meets the condition(s) of the premise, but *defies* the conclusion, and you can conclude the proposition is false.

Comment: Always nicely written responses +1